# Fork Join with generic monad scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, scalaz, scala-cats

Is it possible to express in a generic way, using cats or scalaz this?

```
val common: F[Common] = ...
val a: F[A] = common.flatMap(commonToA)
val b: F[B] = common.flatMap(commonToB)
val result: F[(A,B)] =  a someFunctionToProduct b
```

And ensure that the `common` effect is effectively executed only once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally know how. I can do instead:

```
val common: F[Common] = ...
val fab = common.flatMap{
  c=>
     commonToA(c).zip(commonToB(c))
}
```